# Access denied to my route, created in module.routing.yml

Tags: 8, routes, users

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out why my custom route is returning a 403 status.

My `routing.yml` file:

```
lightbox.content:
  path: '/lightbox/content'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\lightbox\Controller\LightboxController::content'
    _title: 'Hello World'
    requirements:
      _permission: 'access content'
      _access: true
```

My `permissions.yml` file

```
access content:
  title: 'Access Content'
  description: 'Read all content'
```

Permission page:
[image: headers]

[image: screenshot from permissions]

Comment: Is requirements really indented like that? Should be the same level as defaults.

Comment: I feel dumb, that was my issue.

Comment: It happens. Look into using a YAML linter (online or offline) it will help out a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The issue, as mentioned in the comment was my indentation.  I will leave this for anyone that may run into this issue.

Comment: One more, *access content* permission was existed, don't need define. And _access: true don't need _permission.